# How can we get weights after training RNN in Keras?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have trained an RNN in Keras. Now, I want to get the values of the trained weights:

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(SimpleRNN(27, return_sequences=True , input_shape=(None, 27), activation = 'softmax'))<br>
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.get_weights()
```

This gives me 2 arrays of shape `(27,27)` and 1 array of shape `(27,1)`. I am not getting the meaning of these arrays. Also, I should get 2 more array of shape `(27,27)` and `(27,1)` that will calculate the hidden state 'a' activation. How can I get these weights?

Answer (score 1):

The arrays returned by `model.get_weights()` directly correspond to the weights used by [`SimpleRNNCell`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#simplernncell). They include:

- The `kernel` matrix of size `(input_shape[-1], units)`. In your case, `input_shape=(None, 27)` and `units=27`, so it's `(27, 27)`. The kernel gets multiplied by the `input`.
- The `recurrent_kernel` matrix of size `(units, units)`, which also happens to be `(27, 27)`. This matrix gets multiplied by the previous state.
- The bias array of shape `(units,) == (27,)`.

These arrays correspond to the standard formula:

```
# W = kernel
# U = recurrent_kernel
# B = bias
output = new_state = act(W * input + U * state + B)
```

Note that keras implementation uses a single bias vector, so all in all there are exactly three arrays.

Comment: To calculate output, we have to multiply the new_state with output_kernel and output_bias. Output = act(Out_kernel * new_state + By)

Comment: So, we should have total 3 kernels of size (27, 27) and 2 bias of size (27,  1)

Comment: That's not the way simple RNN cell works. The right formula is in the answer. The only library that has more than 3 parameter arrays is pytorch - they use two bias vectors and two kernels. Keras uses a single bias vector. See this discussion: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/30317/18375